# Need to fetch Boolean type column as varchar from source table and store as varchar in target table in Amazon redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have been working with redshift for a month. I need your help regarding this;

I need to create a target table using source table (create table target as select * from source), there is a column in source table type of boolean, I need to store that column as varchar in target table. Tried lots of methods like cast, convert..etc nothing worked for me. After done with lots of search, I got to know that boolean cannot be converted to another data type in redshift.

It shows me below error;

> Amazon Invalid operation: column "indicator" is of
> type boolean but expression is of type character varying; [SQL
> State=42804, DB Errorcode=500310] 1 statement failed.

I shall be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach might work for your case.

When loading the data from source table, instead of selecting all the columns using `SELECT *`, you explicitly call out the individual columns and for the boolean column use a [case expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CASE_function.html) and evaluate the actual data and return the result as string `'true'` or `'false'`.

```
create table target as select colA, colB, case boolColC when true then 'true' else 'false' end from source
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't convert directly from Boolean to varchar, you could use

```
CASE 
    WHEN boolCol= TRUE THEN 'True'
    WHEN boolCol= FALSE THEN 'False'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS boolCol
```

to sidestep the need for conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but It doesn't work using case well. I tried update query; update table
set indicator= 
case indicator when true then 'true'
when false then 'false'
else 'N/A' end ------- It throws this error "[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "indicator" is of type boolean but expression is of type text; [SQL State=42804, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed."

Comment: It needs to be done at table creation as Sivakumar suggested.  That way your column will be created with the varchar type and not the boolean type. I should have been clearer in my answer. You should drop and recreate your table, that would be the easiest solution.

Comment: It can be jist `WHEN boolCol` and `WHEN NOT boolCol`. The column is already boolean, you do not need to compare with TRUE or FALSE to produce anoter boolean result

Comment: True, but that's more of an optimisation concern. I find it more readable that way when using column name that don't really indicate the column is a boolean (unlike for example 'IsAvailable').

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue using nested case statement at the time of table creation - I am posting the solution here so that It can be helpful for others as well.

```
case 
  when name in ('a', 'b') then 
  case offline_crt when true then 'true' else 'false' end
  else 'N/A'
  end as indicator
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I was also facing ,please check below how I fixed it.

In my original code one column having **Boolean** data type and when I was doing union of two table it was failing due to below error.

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: UNION types character varying and boolean cannot be matched;
```

I have attached the screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Now I have just used the case statement inside the select for the Boolean data type column and it's working fine.

[image]